# An application which adds +5 every 24 hours

Tags: java, android, timer

I am working on an app which counts +5 every 24 hours, but time on device should not influence this timer. For instance, if it is 9:00 AM on the clock and 20 minutes on the timer, and user sets device time to 9:15, timer should still have 20 minutes to count.

Comment: very perplexing projection

Comment: Use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: Does it influence by system time?

Comment: Does it have a network connection allowing to use an online server to get the time ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two general clock types for alarms: "elapsed real time" and "real time clock" (RTC). Elapsed real time uses the "time since system boot" as a reference, and real time clock uses UTC (wall clock) time. This means that elapsed real time is suited to setting an alarm based on the passage of time (for example, an alarm that fires every 30 seconds) since it isn't affected by time zone/locale. The real time clock type is better suited for alarms that are dependent on current locale.

You can use AlarmManager with RTC as following

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,DAILY_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE, yourIntent,           

                                          PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setcalendar.getTimeInMillis(), 

    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

And Then use a BroadcastReciever to get the event and do your stuff :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Your logic here

    }

}
```

Comment: But isn't it depending on the uptime of the device ? So if you reboot the device, this is reseted with it ?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `android.net.SntpClient` which is a simple SNTP client for retrieving the time from a SNTP service:

```
SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
if (client.requestTime("time.foo.com")) {
    long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - client.getNtpTimeReference();
}
```

You can find the implementation [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/SntpClient.java).